# Pandas is not formatting the date as asked

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column called Pausetime and another one called Worktime.
Both of them are strings and look like this: "02:28:49".
I want to convert them from strings  to date objects; however, keep the format `%H%M%S`
I am using the following line:

```
# define the format of the time columns
time_format = "%H:%M:%S"

# convert the time columns
df["Pausetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Pausetime"], format=time_format)
df["Worktime"]  = pd.to_datetime(df["Worktime"],  format=time_format)

print(df["Worktime"])
```

The output, however, is not as the passed time_format

```
1   1900-01-01 02:28:49
2   1900-01-01 04:47:45
3   1900-01-01 04:49:09
4   1900-01-01 02:46:47
Name: Worktime, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

**Any Tips on how to achieve this?**
I am new to Pandas and kinda lost in this issue.

*The reason is I am calculating the time later on in Excel, and apparently, it only works if the cell is date formatted.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need datetimes objects with only times and without dates it is not possible in python.

You can convert values to times:

```
df["Pausetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Pausetime"], format=time_format).dt.time
df["Worktime"]  = pd.to_datetime(df["Worktime"],  format=time_format).dt.time

print (df['Worktime'])
0    02:28:49
1    04:47:45
2    04:49:09
Name: Worktime, dtype: object
```

Or to timedeltas, but format is different:

```
df["Pausetime"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["Pausetime"])
df["Worktime"]  = pd.to_timedelta(df["Worktime"])

print (df['Worktime'])
0   0 days 02:28:49
1   0 days 04:47:45
2   0 days 04:49:09
Name: Worktime, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: That is a great answer; however, the type cannot be String(object)
For some reason, excel is having issues calculating the time if it was a string.

Comment: @AssadRajab - try `timedelta`s, it should working well

Comment: I See; it works, but in the outputted Excel file (generated via xlsxwriter), the time appears as 0, but it has an initial value if manually reformatted to hh-mm-ss. Can you suggest anything to solve this?

Comment: @AssadRajab - In output is format like `0 days 04:49:09` and need convert it to `04:49:09` ?

Comment: Using print, it is outputting ``0 days 04:49:09``; once I write it to Excel, the cell shows 0. If I manually format that cell (in Excel) to date format, it shows ``04:49:09``.  I belive this is an xlsxwritter formatting issue, not a data frame format issue.

Answer (score 0):

In pd.to_datetime(), the format parameter is used to specify the format of the input datetime string that you are trying to convert into a pandas Datetime object. By providing the correct format, you ensure that pandas can parse the string correctly and convert it into a datetime object.

To change the format of a pandas Datetime object, you can use the strftime() method as so:

```
import pandas as pd

datetime_obj = pd.to_datetime("2021-09-30 10:15:30")

formatted_time = datetime_obj.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
print(formatted_time)
```

Comment: Can this method be applied to the whole column at once?

Comment: sure ! `df['time_formatted'] = df['datetime'].dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")`

Comment: Btw, this solution create strings column.

Answer (score 0):

**!UPDATED!**

**Note:** Before applying the solution below, I assume you don't have any missing values in these columns. Otherwise, that might be the problem. In that case, you can do something like this:

```
time_format = "%H:%M:%S"
df["Pausetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Pausetime"], format=time_format, errors='coerce')
df["Worktime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Worktime"], format=time_format, errors='coerce')
```

After converting to datetime, you can try to use `.dt.strftime` I assume it will solve your problem.
Like this:

```
time_format = "%H:%M:%S"

df["Pausetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Pausetime"], format=time_format)
df["Worktime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Worktime"], format=time_format)

#df["Pausetime"] = df["Pausetime"].dt.strftime(time_format)
#df["Worktime"] = df["Worktime"].dt.strftime(time_format)

df["Pausetime"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["Pausetime"].dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
df["Worktime"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["Worktime"].dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

I hope this will work. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the missing values. I do prepare the data before applying this method. Anyway, your answer is excellent. However, it creates string columns, which will cause difficulties later on while calculating the time.